# How to add extra tab bar button in tab bar controller without adding view controller on that button in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

How to add tab bar item in tab bar view controller without adding a view controller with that and tap on that button no view controller are open. Tap on that tap bar button a alert will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On view did load create a UITabBarItem programmatically with a special tag. In your tab controller set the delegate to your view controller. On the method

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar
 didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Check to see if the item has your custom tag and if so present an alert.  If it requires a view to be linked with the UITabBarItem simply just set a view of another UITabBarItem for your alert view bar item.

Comment: in which class I create a UITabBarItem.

Comment: Do you need help creating and adding a bar item?